# How do I set msExchMailboxGUID using powershell or any other method?

Tags: exchange-2010, powershell, active-directory

I need to set the msExchMailboxGUID for many accounts in bulk.  My input for this data comes from the Powershell command Get-MailboxStatistics.  In it is an object that has the GUID for the mailbox.

I need to save that GUID into AD, so this is what I'm doing to GET the object:

```
   $thisDN = $oneUser.DistinguishedName
   $user = [ADSI]"LDAP://$thisDN"  

  try 
  {
     $user.get("msExchMailboxGUID")
  }
  catch
  {
      $desc = ""
  }
```

What is the correct way to Set the object?

I'm unable to use "set" or "put" to upload and save the error.  It would even be better if someone can point me to detailed object details since I'm not sure where to look for details on something that is instantiated with the `[ADSI]` brackety thing.

If this is just using the COM ADSI objects, then what is the correct syntax for "put"?  I've tried parentheses, commas, and am unable to get Powershell to talk COM.

Comment: Do you not have available the Microsoft ActiveDirectory modules included with RSAT? Are you using ADSI for a specific reason?

Comment: @jscott I thought ADSI was the way... perhaps this is a lot easier than I thought.  What term should I google?  My search terms lead me down the ADSI path.

Comment: Hmmm seems like `Import-Module ActiveDirectory` may help me

Answer (score 2):

Continuing from your example, this would work:

```
$guid = $user.get("msExchMailboxGUID")

$thisDN2 = $twoUser.DistinguishedName
$user2 = [ADSI]"LDAP://$thisDN2"

$user2.put('msExchMailboxGUID', @($guid))
$user2.setinfo()
```

Answer (score 1):

In case Google leads anyone else here, here is the easiest way to do this. This requires the Active Directory PowerShell module, which comes with RSAT. [See here](https://4sysops.com/wiki/how-to-install-the-powershell-active-directory-module/) for more info on installing it.

Active Directory stores the GUID as a byte array, so in order to set it we need to convert our GUID string to a byte array.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
set-aduser jim.bob -Replace @{msExchMailboxGuid=$([System.Guid]"f750b85a-ebae-48ec-9add-2224df22000a").ToByteArray()}
```

Replace the username and GUID in the example above with your own values.